# web.xml or @WebServlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am learning how to create web servlets in eclipse using apache tomcat 7.0. Most of the examples are shown with web.xml file where I do not have. Should I create web.xml or using @WebServlet annotation will do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well its actually good to use annotations, only issue is you have to search the configuration files. This is not the case for xml based configuration.

You can simply implement the web servlet, no need to create xml

```
@WebServlet (name="Xyz", urlPatterns={"/*"}, initParams =     {@WebInitParam(name="test",value="annotation")}) 
public class GenServlet extends HttpServlet{
```

You can find more details and examples here http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/webservlet-annotation-examples

Hope this helps

Comment: that was helpful, thanks but i am not very clear at what you mean by configuration files.

Comment: Configurtion files are like web.xml for servlet and spring config file.